# Выполнить команду по завершении потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Вворачиваю в *самопальный* лаунчер для *самопальных* программ систему обновления.
У меня есть готовая процедура обновления, которая запускается отдельным потоком для каждой доступной программы в лаунчере, через `foreach()` (проверяет наличие новых файлов и загржаует их с сервера).

Есть момент на котором я встрял: при нажатии на кнопку запуска приложения из лаунчера должны проверяться обновления только для этой программы, а после должен производиться ее запуск.

Обновиться то она обновляется, но вот с пост-апдейтным запуском проблема. **Как мне, не впихивая в поточную процедуру запуск приложения дождаться завершения конкретного потока и только потом выполнить команду?**

На кнопку прописан код, например, такой:

```
Thread updateThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CheckAndLoadUpdateFiles));
updateThread.Start(<appdata>);

StartAppliction(<appdata>.<appname>, <appdata>.<apppath>, <appdata>.<appparams>);
```

Я знаю, что `StartApplication` выполнится сразу после старта потока и не хочу пихать эту процедуру в процедуру обновления.

Жду ваших предложения и советов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создание потока - ресурсоёмкая операция. Вместо создания потока вы можете использовать пул потоков. Также само ожидание вы можете сделать асинхронным. Пример:

```
async void buttonRun_Click()
{
    await Task.Run(()=>CheckAndLoadUpdateFiles(<appdata>));
    StartAppliction(<appdata>.<appname>, <appdata>.<apppath>, <appdata>.<appparams>);
}
```

ну или так

```
async void buttonRun_Click()
{
    await Task.Run(()=>CheckAndLoadUpdateFiles(<appdata>));
    await Task.Run(()=>StartAppliction(<appdata>.<appname>, <appdata>.<apppath>, <appdata>.<appparams>));       
}
```

На худой конец так

```
void buttonRun_Click()
{
    Task.Run(() => CheckAndLoadUpdateFiles(<appdata>))
        .ContinueWith(t=>StartAppliction(<appdata>.<appname>, <appdata>.<apppath>, <appdata>.<appparams>));     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ожидание завершения потока:

```
updateThread.Join();
```

Вот описание функции https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=netcore-2.1

Думаю есть смыл запускать новый поток, в котором будет:

1. Запуск потока обновления
2. Ожидание завершения потока обновления
3. Запуск приложения

Однако не исключаю, что есть более лаконичное решение, что бы не запускать потоки. Можно рассмотреть вариант реализации через *Tack*.

**UPDATE**

Вот пример кода:

```
void buttonRun_Click()
{
    Thread updateAndLaunchThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadUpdateAndLaunch));
    updateAndLaunchThread.Start();
}

void ThreadUpdateAndLaunch()
{
    Thread updateThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CheckAndLoadUpdateFiles));
    updateThread.Start(<appdata>);

    updateThread.Join();

    StartAppliction(<appdata>.<appname>, <appdata>.<apppath>, <appdata>.<appparams>);
}
```

Comment: То есть, если я правильно понимаю, то запускаем поток, в котором запускается поток обновления и делаем для первого Join чтобы он остановился дожидаясь окончания второго?

Comment: @Rekssel Да, верно. Добавил в ответ свой пример, посмотрите.